# No encuentro como cambiar el color de fondo, siempre es blanco o puede cambiarse?

Tags: tkinter, tree

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import shutil
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter.font as tkFont


def proyecto():
    def salir_app():
        if messagebox.askyesno('Atencion','Se dispone a Salir del Administrador de proyectos.') == True:
            app.deiconify()
            proyecto.destroy()
    proyecto=Toplevel()
    proyecto.resizable(0,0)
    proyecto.config(bg='Black')
    proyecto.overrideredirect(True)
    fontStyle = tkFont.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=20)
    fontStyle1 = tkFont.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=30)
    fontStyle2 = tkFont.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=10)
    #----------------------------TAMANO Y POSISION DE LA VENTANA----------------------------------
    ancho_ventana = 500
    alto_ventana = 500
    x_ventana = proyecto.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - ancho_ventana // 2
    y_ventana = proyecto.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - alto_ventana // 2
    posicion = str(ancho_ventana) + "x" + str(alto_ventana) + "+" + str(x_ventana) + "+" + str(y_ventana)
    proyecto.geometry(posicion)
    proyecto.resizable(0,0)
    proyecto.title("DGQ-PROYECT MANAGER")
    #----------------------------TAMANO Y POSISION DE LA VENTANA----------------------------------
    Label(proyecto, text='PROJECT MANAGEMENT BY', bg='Black',fg='White',font=fontStyle).place(x=10, y=5)
    Label(proyecto, text='DGQ', bg='Black',fg='Red',font=fontStyle1).place(x=390, y=0)

    espacio=LabelFrame(proyecto, text='TOOLS Proyect:', bg='Black',fg='White')
    espacio.place(x=10,y=50,width=239,height=125)

    Button(espacio, text="New!",width=10, command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Green').place(x=10, y=10)
    Button(espacio, text="Edit!",width=10, command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Yellow').place(x=10, y=40)
    Button(espacio, text="Delete!",width=10, command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Red').place(x=10, y=70)

    espacio1=LabelFrame(proyecto, text='EXTRA TOOLS:', bg='Black',fg='White')
    espacio1.place(x=250,y=50,width=240,height=125)

    Button(espacio1, text="Employees!",width=10,command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Green').place(x=10, y=10)
    Button(espacio1, text="Exit!",width=10,command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Red').place(x=10, y=70)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label(proyecto,text='Registered Jobs:', bg='Black',fg='White',font=fontStyle2).place(x=10, y=180)
    Label(proyecto,text='Registered Employees:', bg='Black',fg='White',font=fontStyle2).place(x=250, y=180)
    cantidad_trabajos=StringVar()
    Entry(proyecto,textvariable=cantidad_trabajos,width=5, state ='readonly').place(x=115, y=182)
    cantidad_empleados=StringVar()
    Entry(proyecto,textvariable=cantidad_empleados,width=5, state ='readonly').place(x=395, y=182)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    tree = ttk.Treeview(proyecto, height = 12, columns=3)#LLAMAMOS AL TREEVIEW
    tree.place(x=10, y=222.5, width= 480)#LO POSICIONAMOS EN LA APP

    proyecto.mainloop()
    introducir el código aquí
proyecto()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes lograrlo utilizando un estilo y un tema para tu ventana

Agregando las siguientes líneas a tu código:

```
# Configurar el estilo y tema
style = ttk.Style(proyecto)
style.theme_use("clam")
# Configurar las propiedades de Treeview
style.configure("Treeview", background="black", fieldbackground="black", foreground="white")
```

Ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import shutil
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter.font as tkFont


def proyecto():
    def salir_app():
        if messagebox.askyesno('Atencion','Se dispone a Salir del Administrador de proyectos.') == True:
            app.deiconify()
            proyecto.destroy()
    proyecto=Toplevel()
    proyecto.resizable(0,0)
    proyecto.config(bg='Black')
    proyecto.overrideredirect(True)
    fontStyle = tkFont.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=20)
    fontStyle1 = tkFont.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=30)
    fontStyle2 = tkFont.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=10)
    #----------------------------TAMANO Y POSISION DE LA VENTANA----------------------------------
    ancho_ventana = 500
    alto_ventana = 500
    x_ventana = proyecto.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - ancho_ventana // 2
    y_ventana = proyecto.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - alto_ventana // 2
    posicion = str(ancho_ventana) + "x" + str(alto_ventana) + "+" + str(x_ventana) + "+" + str(y_ventana)
    proyecto.geometry(posicion)
    proyecto.resizable(0,0)
    proyecto.title("DGQ-PROYECT MANAGER")
    #----------------------------TAMANO Y POSISION DE LA VENTANA----------------------------------
    Label(proyecto, text='PROJECT MANAGEMENT BY', bg='Black',fg='White',font=fontStyle).place(x=10, y=5)
    Label(proyecto, text='DGQ', bg='Black',fg='Red',font=fontStyle1).place(x=390, y=0)

    espacio=LabelFrame(proyecto, text='TOOLS Proyect:', bg='Black',fg='White')
    espacio.place(x=10,y=50,width=239,height=125)

    Button(espacio, text="New!",width=10, command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Green').place(x=10, y=10)
    Button(espacio, text="Edit!",width=10, command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Yellow').place(x=10, y=40)
    Button(espacio, text="Delete!",width=10, command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Red').place(x=10, y=70)

    espacio1=LabelFrame(proyecto, text='EXTRA TOOLS:', bg='Black',fg='White')
    espacio1.place(x=250,y=50,width=240,height=125)

    Button(espacio1, text="Employees!",width=10,command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Green').place(x=10, y=10)
    Button(espacio1, text="Exit!",width=10,command=salir_app, bg='Black',fg='Red').place(x=10, y=70)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label(proyecto,text='Registered Jobs:', bg='Black',fg='White',font=fontStyle2).place(x=10, y=180)
    Label(proyecto,text='Registered Employees:', bg='Black',fg='White',font=fontStyle2).place(x=250, y=180)
    cantidad_trabajos=StringVar()
    Entry(proyecto,textvariable=cantidad_trabajos,width=5, state ='readonly').place(x=115, y=182)
    cantidad_empleados=StringVar()
    Entry(proyecto,textvariable=cantidad_empleados,width=5, state ='readonly').place(x=395, y=182)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Configurar el estilo y tema
    style = ttk.Style(proyecto)
    style.theme_use("clam")
    # Configurar las propiedades de Treeview
    style.configure("Treeview", background="black", fieldbackground="black", foreground="white")
    
    tree = ttk.Treeview(proyecto, height = 12, columns=3)#LLAMAMOS AL TREEVIEW
    tree.place(x=10, y=222.5, width= 480)#LO POSICIONAMOS EN LA APP

    proyecto.mainloop()
    #introducir el código aquí
proyecto()
```

Esto crea la siguiente ventana

[image: TreeView fondo negro]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me has ayudado muchisimo. bendiciones para usted.